# How to configure SWI-prolog with Java on Eclipse on OS X (JPL)

Tags: eclipse, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I am trying to get Java and Prolog to work together (on OS X 10.11.1). What I want, is just to input my Prolog Queries from Java.

When I run Java code such like

```
PrologProcess process = Connector.newPrologProcess();
process.queryOnce(query);
```

I get the following Error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "swipl": error=2, No such file                  or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
...
```

First I did was adding entries to my PATH variable as I suppose that SWIProlog could not been found, but it showed no effect.
My PATH contains:

```
/opt/local/lib/swipl-7.2.3/
/opt/local/lib/swipl-7.2.3/bin
/opt/local/lib/swipl-7.2.3/bin/x86_64-darwin15.0.0/swipl
/opt/local/lib/swipl-7.2.3/bin/swipl.home
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/jpl.jar
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/bin/x86_64-       darwin15.0.0/swipl
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/
```

Hope somebody knows whats up.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Several of your `PATH` entries make no sense. Try on Terminal.app window:

```
$ which swipl
```

That will tell where the `swipl` executable is located. As it seems that you also have installed the `SWI-Prolog.app` GUI application, the correct path to the executable is:

```
/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

Also note that Mac OS X GUI applications don't run on top of a shell and thus don't inherit the environment variable definitions that you use for command-line commands. But Eclipse allows in one of its preferences panel to define environment variables there.

Comment: thank You very much! unfortunately the problem is not solved the error message is:

Comment: // Field descriptor #8    Lorg/cs3/prolog/connector/internal/process/socket/JackTheProcessRipper;

Comment: The connection between PDT and the SWI-Prolog process uses sockets. Check that the SWI-Prolog process is accepting connections in the Mac OS X Security & Private control panel under Firewall Options.

Comment: Compiled from SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy.java (version 1.7 : 51.0, super bit)
public class org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.socket.SocketServerStartAndStopStrategy implements org.cs3.prolog.connector.internal.process.ServerStartAndStopStrategy {

Comment: the message i see that the source attachment does not contain the source for the file socket ServerStartAndStopStrategy.class ... ist it not seen? not compatible or not available?

Comment: Once the structure is build correctly and intelligent,  IT WORKS SOO ELEGANT, AND IT IS SOOOO MIGHTY! JUST AMAZING!!!